# Cannot transfer ajax post data from js to php file

Tags: php, ajax

I need to click on the button to send some data to the php file and update the user's balance in the database.

quotes.js
Part of the code:

```
var data = {
    sell: sell_current_quote,
    buy: bue_current_quote
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-content/themes/NAME/page-trading.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function(my_data) {
        alert('Ok');
    }
});
```

page-trading.php
Part of the code:

```
if( isset($_POST['sell']) && isset($_POST['buy']) ) {

$sell = json_decode($_POST['sell']);
$buy = json_decode($_POST['buy']);

global $wpdb, $userdata;

$wpdb->update( PREF .'users_balance', 
    array(
        'user_balance_2' => 100
    ), 
    array(
        'user_id'      => $userdata->id,
        'user_schet_2' => 00000001,
    ), 
    array("%d","%d")
);

die();
}
```

As a result, the database is not updated.
in the console, in data headers come about
sell: 0.99788
buy: 0

Tell me, please, how to do it right?

Comment: Do you happen to know about built in ajax handler in WordPress. You can probably use that: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: You're using a constant, `PREF`, that is not defined anywhere in your code, and you're using `$wpdb`, which is also not defined unless you load WordPress. See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) for the proper way to use AJAX in WordPress.